# Compiling SuiteSparse in Ubuntu, breaks when installing CHOLMOD

Tags: c++, c, linux, makefile, suitesparse

I've downloaded the .zip for SuiteSparse from the following [GitHub](https://github.com/DrTimothyAldenDavis/SuiteSparse/tree/v5.5.0). I'm trying to install/compile the C/C++ libraries in Ubuntu. I'm using the Windows Subsystem for Linux and installed Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store.

The SuiteSparse instructions say to cd to the SuiteSparse-5.5.0 directory and just type `make`. Makefile [here](https://github.com/DrTimothyAldenDavis/SuiteSparse/blob/v5.5.0/Makefile). The readme suggests that I need make, g++, gcc, and cmake, so I've installed those using `sudo apt install <package name>`. Here's the error message I get from `make 2>error`:

```
/mnt/c/Users/Anshu/path/to/SuiteSparse-5.5.0/metis-5.1.0/GKlib/csr.c: In function ‘gk_csr_Normalize’:
/mnt/c/Users/Anshu/path/to/SuiteSparse-5.5.0/metis-5.1.0/GKlib/csr.c:1344:9: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
    else if (norm == 1)
         ^~
/mnt/c/Users/Anshu/path/to/SuiteSparse-5.5.0/metis-5.1.0/GKlib/csr.c:1346:11: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
           for (j=ptr[i]; j<ptr[i+1]; j++)
           ^~~
/mnt/c/Users/Anshu/path/to/SuiteSparse-5.5.0/metis-5.1.0/GKlib/csr.c:1371:9: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
    else if (norm == 1)
         ^~
/mnt/c/Users/Anshu/path/to/SuiteSparse-5.5.0/metis-5.1.0/GKlib/csr.c:1373:11: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
           for (j=ptr[i]; j<ptr[i+1]; j++)
           ^~~
/mnt/c/Users/Anshu/path/to/SuiteSparse-5.5.0/metis-5.1.0/GKlib/getopt.c: In function ‘gk_getopt_internal’:
/mnt/c/Users/Anshu/path/to/SuiteSparse-5.5.0/metis-5.1.0/GKlib/getopt.c:343:5: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
     if (gk_optind == 0)
     ^~
/mnt/c/Users/Anshu/path/to/SuiteSparse-5.5.0/metis-5.1.0/GKlib/getopt.c:345:7: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
       optstring = gk_getopt_initialize (argc, argv, optstring);
       ^~~~~~~~~
/mnt/c/Users/Anshu/path/to/SuiteSparse-5.5.0/metis-5.1.0/GKlib/getopt.c:700:2: warning: this ‘else’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  else
  ^~~~
/mnt/c/Users/Anshu/path/to/SuiteSparse-5.5.0/metis-5.1.0/GKlib/getopt.c:703:4: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘else’
    nextchar = NULL;
    ^~~~~~~~
ar: creating libsuitesparseconfig.a
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-Woverloaded-virtual’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
ar: creating libamd.a
ar: creating libbtf.a
ar: creating libcamd.a
ar: creating libccolamd.a
ar: creating libcolamd.a
ar: creating libcholmod.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [/mnt/c/Users/Anshu/path/to/SuiteSparse-5.5.0/lib/libcholmod.so.3.0.13] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [library] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [go] Error 2
```

I've turned off my antivirus, which had been preventing the makefile from writing in some folders. What might be going wrong? It seems like the makefile tries to install a bunch of libraries starting with CHOLMOD, and gets stalled while doing that. I've read some [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784238/cant-execute-makefile-in-windows-7) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828792/how-to-compile-cholmod-library-suitesparse-from-ide). The first one doesn't seem to apply here since I didn't change PATH, and the second one suggests using Metis which I'm already doing.

Comment: The linker misses two libraries: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack` and `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install LLAPACK and OpenBLAS development libraries. On Ubuntu the command is:

```
sudo apt install liblapack-dev  libopenblas-dev
```